# How do I simulate an audio amplifier in Multisim?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, dc, signal, multisim

I'm new to Multisim and am using the 12.0 PowerPro version. I have designed the circuit in the question [TDA2002 Audio Amplifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32655/problems-in-8w-audio-amplifier-using-tda2002) using Multisim:

[image: TDA2002 Audio Amplifier]

The Multisim circuit may be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6wqagtjuaefnvn/Audio%20amp.ms12). Instead of a function generator or AC signal, is it possible to input an audio file and see its output in an oscilloscope?

Comment: This help? http://forums.ni.com/t5/Circuit-Design-Suite-Multisim/import-and-saving-wav-file-in-Multisim/td-p/1045190

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams convert your comment to an answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: Thanks to all of you for keeping this post active and relevant :P

Comment: @HarshaCAlva That, sir, was nicely done!

Comment: @AnindoGhosh, you're welcome :P without this community, this circuit, that I started designing two years ago, wouldn't see its light of day :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gorik on the NI forums has ["created a labview instrument" for importing and "asynchronous" simulation of .wav files](http://forums.ni.com/t5/Circuit-Design-Suite-Multisim/import-and-saving-wav-file-in-Multisim/td-p/1045190). It was written for Multisim 11 though, and I'm not sure what effort would be required to use it in 12.